# Modulus of a random variable which follows a continuous uniform distribution, follows which distribution?

Tags: transformation, uniform-distribution

Let $X \sim U(\theta,0),$ $\theta<0$
(continuous uniform distribution)

I want a transformation on $X$ so that it follows $U(0,1)$ distribution
I did $|X|/\theta\sim U(0,1).$ Am I right?

Comment: @angryavian : No, it does not work, since it was given that $\theta<0,$ and clearly $X\ge0. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Sorry, I meant $\frac{X-(-\theta)}{0-\theta} = 1-\frac{X}{\theta}$ rather than $\frac{X}{\theta} - 1$. And I am not sure what you mean by $X \ge 0$, since $X$ is uniform on $[\theta, 0]$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $|X|>0$ and $\theta<0,$ $|X|/\theta$ will be negative.

But $X/\theta$ will serve.

For $x\in[0,1],$ $\quad\Pr(X/\theta\le x) = \Pr(X\ge \theta x) = \dfrac{0-\theta x}{\theta} = x.$

Comment: I got it ,thank you